# Reference scala file from build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following problem: I need to write a file into a build directory with the content that is defined in the project sbt is going to build.

```
prj
 |
 |_src/main/scala/FancyScalaFile.scala
 |
 |_build.sbt
 |
 |_project/build.properties
```

Here is how the `FancyScalaFile.scala` looks like

```
object FancyScalaFile {

    def extractString: String() = //...
}
```

Is there a way to call `extractString` from `build.sbt`?

Comment: No. Your built tool can not use the logic it is trying to build... However, you can have a Scala file on `project/` which you can use on your build tool.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Even after the project is built?

Comment: For what do you need that value?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Well, actually this is possible.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez For example sharing some code between build project and main project can be useful for multi-staging programming when during next stage you use code generated during previous stage (pre-compile-time replacement for macros) and you want to use build time as one of stages. Although I surely can't know actual OP's use case.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Actually I have a Scala file that is able to generate a documentation. I want to use it to build a package with the documentation during the build phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can [add](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html#Add+an+additional+source+directory) additional source directory to `project/build.sbt` (create this file if it doesn't exist; do not confuse it with `build.sbt` in the project root directory)

```
Compile / unmanagedSourceDirectories += baseDirectory.value / ".." / "src" / "main" / "scala"
```

After that you'll be able to call `FancyScalaFile.extractString()` in `build.sbt`.

For example if `FancyScalaFile` is

```
object FancyScalaFile {
  def extractString(): String = "scala-reflect"
}
```

then you can write the following in `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % FancyScalaFile.extractString() % scalaVersion.value
```

and project is built successfully adding `scala-reflect` dependency.