# Calling a generic scala method in groovy

Tags: scala, groovy, interop, implicit

I am trying to call a method from an external scala library in a groovy class.

The library method has the signature:

```
def ofType[T: ClassTag](bundle: Bundle): Iterable[T]
```

The call `ofType<Data>(bundle)` results in the error `Groovyc: unable to resolve class ofType <Data>`

I can call other methods from this library without issue, is there a way to correctly call this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def ofType[T: ClassTag](bundle: Bundle)
```

is desugared into

```
def ofType[T](bundle: Bundle)(implicit ctag: ClassTag[T])
```

so you'll have to resolve implicit manually.

Try to call

```
obj.<Data>ofType(bundle, ClassTag.apply(Data.class))
```

or just

```
ofType(bundle, ClassTag.apply(Data.class))
```

I [guess](https://ideone.com/ZTCdWW), in Groovy a type parameter is specified at a method call site like in Java as `obj.<A>method(params)`, not as `obj.method<A>(params)`.

Scala multiple parameter lists

```
def ofType[T](bundle: Bundle)(implicit ctag: ClassTag[T])
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

are seen in Java as a single parameter list. I guess this can be similar in Groovy.

---

Groovy-Scala interop of generics depends on the version of Groovy. In [How to call a scala method from build.gradle file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64064619/how-to-call-a-scala-method-from-build-gradle-file) I noticed that in Groovy 3.0.5 all the following declarations work

```
import shapeless.*

$colon$colon l =
  new $colon$colon(1, new $colon$colon("a", new HNil$()))
$colon$colon<Int, $colon$colon> l =
  new $colon$colon(1, new $colon$colon("a", new HNil$()))
$colon$colon<Int, $colon$colon<String, HNil>> l =
  new $colon$colon(1, new $colon$colon("a", new HNil$()))
HList l =
  new $colon$colon(1, new $colon$colon("a", new HNil$()))
def l =
  new $colon$colon(1, new $colon$colon("a", new HNil$()))
```

while in Groovy 2.5.10 only the last 2 declarations work.